# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fadeOut' of undefined

Tags: jquery

everyone

I'm getting an error from some of my code below. Here is the code :

```
jQuery("body").queryLoader2({
barColor: "#3899b5",
backgroundColor: "#fff",
percentage: true,
barHeight: 4,
completeAnimation: "grow",
minimumTime: 500,
onComplete : function () { 
self.loader.fadeOut(200);
            }});
```

Best regards,
Ko

Comment: if possible give us fiddle

Comment: sorry Pandiyan Cool , I can't make it work on fiddle :(